# Order of facets block change after the research

Tags: ajax, search

I'm new in Drupal and I have a problem when I use *search ajaxified* with *search api* and facet block.

My research works fine: When I click on the facet block that contains tags for example, my results are fine. After, my block are not anymore in the same order than before.

**For instance, before I click on one tag, the order are like this (all my blocks are in the left sidebar and so in the same region):**

- navigation
- Facet API: content type
- Facet API: Tags
- Saved search

**After the reseach in Ajax:**

- navigation
- Saved search
- Facet API: content type
- Facet API: Tags

All my Facets blocks are now at the bottom.

I followed all the instructions on Drupal.org given by the author of the module, and they worked fine, I just don't understand why my facet block are not in the same order after the ajax search. I've been trying for a couple days and cannot figure out a cause for this. Has anybody encountered this before?

Maybe I need to create another region to put only my facet block in, but I think there must be a better solution than that.

Comment: Are these blocks placed there with a context?  If they all have the same weight, their order may not be as permanent as you think... Let me know how you placed the blocks on the page.

Comment: So i used seach api => facets and i checked the facet i wanted to be enabled in block. In fact after i just use structure -> block and put them in regions['sidebar-left']...After i just create a view for my result and it's all...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the block weights, but just in case, can you see what I mean by making sure they're distinct.

Verify the below and see if you still have the same issue:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the blocks weight are good, all the number are distinct...I don't know what to do but i hope i will find a solution :) Thanks again